# I want to show all tooltip box in a fixed position

Tags: javascript, css

I am using [intro-js](https://usablica.github.io/intro.js/) plugin, I want to show all tooltips in a fixed position. to see the demo [click here](https://usablica.github.io/intro.js/)

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/pyt8jnan , i have added this style : `.introjs-tooltip {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0px !important;
    left: 0px !important;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below style to make the position fixed in the page. `!important` is the real doer here.

```
.introjs-tooltip {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0px !important;
    left: 0px !important;
}
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/pyt8jnan